# is k-means generalizable at any distance?

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

The classical version of k-means uses the Euclidean distance in the first step, and the arithmetic mean (the value center) in the second step. Is k-means generalizable to other distances and other operations than the arithmetic mean so that it converges?

There are special cases like k-median, where the distance is city-block, and the center's value is the median of the cluster points.

Comment: Yes, you can use any distance metric that you prefer. Although you should be able to explain why you chose that particular metric.

Comment: Is it possible to choose any distance while setting the arithmetic mean as a choice in the second step?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can do it, however you will probably have to implement it yourself. I don't know of any which will let you choose.

Comment: I am looking for a general theoretical framework of the applicability of k-means over any distance while allowing k-means to converge.

Comment: Distance between what and what? Between data points or between a data point and a cluster centre?

Comment: This sort of question has bern asked multiple times here. Search the site, for example "k-means distance".

Answer (score 1):

No, k-means is for euclidean distance. An alternative similar version of it is called [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) where centers are chosen amongst data points, and can be used with arbitrary distance metrics.